# Angular 9: Changing image URL after retrieving from server

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 9 and have a proxy up and running, but when I retrieve data from the server as JSON, Angular is changing the image URL to use `localhost:4200`.

For example: Using Postman, when I check the data retrieved I get the expected return data:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "titulo": "Titulo 1",
    "slug": "slug",
    "descricao": "descricao",
    "precoAtual": 10,
    "precoAnterior": 15,
    "possuiDesconto": 1,
    "percDesconto": 15,
    "src": "http://localhost/myprojects/galix/trunk/laravel/public/img-produtos/1out.jpg",
    "srcOut": "http://localhost/myprojects/galix/trunk/laravel/public/img-produtos/1out.jpg",
    "srcOn": "http://localhost/myprojects/galix/trunk/laravel/public/img-produtos/1on.jpg",
    "created_at": "2020-05-09T20:37:23.000000Z",
    "updated_at": null
  }
]
```

But when I do a `console.log` on Angular, I noticed that the image URL was changed to use `localhost:4200`.

```
…
src: "http://localhost:4200/myprojects/galix/trunk/laravel/public/img-produtos/1out.jpg"
…
```

Why is this happening? I don't even have an `/api/` on the URL to take into consideration API CALL related issues.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Need to see related codes

Comment: why does it come from the server 'http: // localhost' and not 'http: // localhost: 8080'?